# Reload Java enum

Tags: java, enums, classloader

I have an app that loads a file when it is started. When the file is loaded some enums are initialized. The method `getTagGroupStartId` is called when the enums are initalized. The method takes the name of a "tag" which may or may not exist in the loaded file. If it does not exist then `getTagGroupStartId` returns `-1`.

All of that is fine. The problem occurs when I load another file that may contain a "tag" that the previous file did not contain or may not contain a "tag" that the previous file did contain. In both cases I need the value of m_tagId in the enum to be updated so the enum reflects the values of the current file. How can I reload / re-initialize the enum?

```
public enum ExampleEnum {

    FOO("FOO_"),
    BAR("BAR_"),
    BAZ("BAZ_");

    private final String m_tagName;
    private final int m_tagId;

    ExampleEnum(String tagName) {
        m_tagName = tagName;
        m_tagId = Tag.getTagGroupStartId(tagName);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Why do you place closing parenthesis on new line? That makes the code very unreadable. It took me some 10 seconds to find out that the code inside `{}` there are part of constructor.

Comment: The enum is massive in my code, so that makes it more readable.  I copied it from my code and removed the noise but didn't change that.  Fixed it here now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following method to your enum:

```
public static void refreshAll() {
    for (ExampleEnum e : values()) {
        e.m_tagId = Tag.getTagGroupStartId(e.m_tagName);
    }
}
```

And call it when you want it to refresh.

Comment: And make the `m_tagId` non-`final` :)